# is it possible to call our server side(like gridview events) event from JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, javascript

```
<img src='<%# "ThumbNailImage.ashx?ImID="+ Eval("ImageID")  %>' id="ImgShow" runat="server"
                                                align="top" style="border: solid 1px Gray;" height="150"  
                                                width="170"  onclick="javascript:myFunction();" >


protected void gvImages_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,  EventArgs e)
    {

        string s = gvImages.SelectedValue.ToString();
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT imagename,ImageID from [Image2] where ImageID='"+s+"' ", connection);
        SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        ada.Fill(dt);
        this.dvCustomerDetail.Visible = true;
        dvCustomerDetail.DataSource = dt;
        dvCustomerDetail.DataBind();
        this.updPnlCustomerDetail.Update();
        this.mdlPopup.Show();

    }

 <script  type ="text/javascript" >
    function myFunction()
    {
    debugger ;
document.getElementById('<%=gvImages.ClientID%>').SelectedIndexChanged();
//__doPostBack('Button1','OnClick');

}
    </script>
```

now in  control i a calling my javascript function from there  i need to call my gvImages_selected index change event.

which is not happening is there any issue in my javascript
any help would be great thank  you

Answer (score 0):

I don´t think you can call the SelectedIndexChange event like that, you need to trigger it from a button in the grid:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged.aspx

You could of course hide the Select button with css, and manually call the `click()` method of the button in the row you wish to switch the index to.

Wrap it in an UpdatePanel, and set the SelectedIndexChange event of the GridView as a trigger for the UpdatePanel.